# Zoom for WP7 app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm lookin for a control for a WP7 app that allows zooming by pinch. I saw on codeplex smth like DeepZoomContener but is doesn't do well. Any ideas? I just need zoom to 150% by pinching that's all.

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thx Mick but this messed up with my layout a bit. I did something more simple.

I use the [Silverlight Toolkit for WP7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/52297) and add the pinch GetureListener to my grid

```
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener PinchDelta="GestureListener_PinchDelta" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

and code in event

```
private void GestureListener_PinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DistanceRatio < 1.0 || e.DistanceRatio > 1.4)
        {
            return;
        }
        // Create the animation for pinch
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation pinchXAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        pinchXAnimation.To = e.DistanceRatio;
        pinchXAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);
        storyboard.Children.Add(pinchXAnimation);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(pinchXAnimation, new PropertyPath("GridScaling.ScaleX"));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(pinchXAnimation, GridScaling);

        DoubleAnimation pinchYAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        pinchYAnimation.To = e.DistanceRatio;
        pinchYAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);
        storyboard.Children.Add(pinchYAnimation);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(pinchYAnimation, new PropertyPath("GridScaling.ScaleY"));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(pinchYAnimation, GridScaling);

        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: Got an error: "Cannot resolve TargetProperty GridScaling.ScaleX on specified object."

Comment: you have to add scale object to the grid         <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="GridScaling" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"  />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>

Answer (score 3):

Checkout Laurent Bugnions control.

[MultiTouch Behavior for Windows Phone 7](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2010/07/04/multitouch-behavior-for-windows-phone-7-videos-wp7dev.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+galasoft+%28Laurent+Bugnion+%28GalaSoft%29%29&utm_content=Twitter)

[MultiTouch Behavior: Update for Windows Phone 7 tools beta](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2010/07/12/multitouch-behavior-update-for-windows-phone-7-tools-beta.aspx)