# Zooming in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, silverlight-toolkit, windows-phone-7, gestures

I want to zoom in/out the canvas in windows phone 7, I have used the windows phone toolkit for
silverlight but it is only zooming a particular item on the canvas like a single image.

In my application i want to zoom in/out canvas in such a way that all elements (images,text) placed on it should perform zoom in/out.

I m also dynamically adding images and text during the runtime using tap.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to zoom in/out the canvas in windows phone 7, I have used the windows phone toolkit for silverlight but it is only zooming a particular item on the canvas like a single image.

I think you are not correctly using it.

I have this problem and I posted the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531806/zoom-for-wp7-app).

Comment: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229125
I am using this as an example. The map can be zoom in and out
but when I add a textbox on the map and than performs zoom in/ out
the text remains fixed whereas the map continues to zoom in/out